# efficiently sample sequences of consecutive integers that terminate in the same number from a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, random, sampling, markov-chains

Suppose I have the following numpy array:

```
Space = np.arange(7)
```

**Question:** How could I generate a set of N samples from Space such that:

1. Each sample consist only of increasing or decreasing consecutive numbers
2. The sampling is done with replacement so the sample need not be monotonically increasing or decreasing.
3. Each sample ends with a 6 or 0, and
4. There is no limitation on the length of the samples (however each sample terminates once a 6 or 0 has been selected).

In essence I'm creating a markov reward process via numpy sampling (There is probably a more efficient packet for this, but i'm not sure what it would be.) For example if N = 3, a possible sampled set would look something like this.

```
Sample = [[1,0],[4, 3, 4, 5, 6],[4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0]]
```

I can accomplish this with something not very elegant like this:

```
N = len(Space)
Set = []
for i in range(3):
    X = np.random.randint(N)
    if (X == 0) | (X==6):
        Set.append(X)
    else:
        Sample = []
        while (X !=0) & (X != 6):
            Next = np.array([X-1, X+1])
            X = np.random.choice(Next)
            Sample.append(X)
        Set.append(Sample)
return(Set)
```

But I was wondering what a more efficient/pythonic way to go about this type of sampling, perhaps without so many loops?  Or alternatively if there are better python libraries for this sort of thing? Thanks.

Comment: I'm quite confused because you said "each sample consists of only increasing/decreasing consecutive numbers", but in your sample set, the samples are not following that order.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, the samples are increasing/decreasing consecutive numbers, but as noted in point 2. they need not be monotonically so.

Comment: Wouldn't that just mean that the second statement contradicts the first, as you *cant* have it such that the sample *only* contains consecutively increasing/decreasing numbers?

Comment: I don't think so.  I can have the sequence 4,5,6.  I can also have 2,1,0. The sequence 1,2,3,4,3,2,1,0 is also not precluded.  So each sample consists of integers.  These integers can increase or decrease consecutively but the sample (i.e. the string of integers) need not be monotonically increasing or decreasing.

Comment: By that, the only requirement is that you don't include the same integer twice back to back, is that true?

Comment: yes that's right.  the numbers have to be consecutive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Numpy doesn't seem to be helping much here, I'd just use the standard `random` module.  The main reason is that `random` faster when working with single values as this algorithm does and there doesn't seem to be any need to pull in an extra dependency unless needed.

```
from random import randint, choice

def bounded_path(lo, hi):
    # r covers the interior space
    r = range(lo+1, hi)
    n = randint(lo, hi)
    result = [n]
    while n in r:
        n += choice((-1, 1))
        result.append(n)
    return result
```

seems to do the right thing for me, e.g. evaluating the above 10 times, I get:

```
[0]
[4, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
[5, 6]
[2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
[1, 0]
[1, 0]
[4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1, 0]
[3, 2, 3, 2, 1, 0]
[6]
[4, 5, 4, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

Just did quick benchmark of random number generation comparing:

```
def rng_np(X):
    for _ in range(10):
        X = np.random.choice(np.array([X-1,X+1]))
    return X

def rng_py(X):
    for _ in range(10):
        X += choice((-1, +1))
    return X
```

The Numpy version is ~30 times slower.  Numpy has to do lots of extra work, building a Python array each iteration, converting to a Numpy array, switching in `choice` to allow for fancy vectorisation.  Python knows that the `(-1, +1)` in the vanilla version is constant, so it's just built once (e.g. [`dis`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html) is useful to see what's going on inside).

You might be able to get somewhere by working with larger blocks of numbers, but I doubt it would be much faster. Maintaining the uniformity of starting point seems awkward, but you could probably do something if you were really careful!  Numpy starts to break even when each call is vectorised over approx 10 values, and really shines when you have more than 100 values.

Comment: Wow I would not have thought of approaching it like this...Thank you for your clear answer and explanation!  I'm just wondering since each subsequent entry is dependent upon the previous entry, does this conditional element rule out all possibilities of vectorization?  Intuitively it seem as though it would, but given that I am not very good at this I thought it would be prudent to check.

Comment: @phntm have added a little benchmark and explanation, hope they help!